# fstream << a(0) << ...<<a(n) vs fstream << a(0); ... fstream <<a(n);

Tags: c++, fstream

Given a number of variables containing data a(1) - a(n), what is the best way to write this data to a file using std::fstream and what are the differences?

if I have an open std::fstream to a file do I use

```
std::fstream << a(0) <<"\t" <<
             << a(1) <<"\t" <<
             ...
             << a(n) <<"\n";
```

or

```
std::fstream << a(0);
std::fstream << "\t";
...
std::fstream << a(n);
std::fstream << "\n";
```

is there a functional or perfomance difference?

Comment: Is `a` a collection/array or a function ?  If `a` is collection/array just iterate over it instead of all the typing.

Comment: Identical performance and result. The first is much less typing.

Comment: @al3c *Much less typing* ... depends on what the name of the `std::fstream` object is. `f << x << y;` and `f << x; f << y;` aren't so different in character counts.

Comment: a is just a placeholder for whatever data you want to dump. My question was more on is it better to concatenate all the fstream operations in one command or separate it in terms of performance and convention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
std::fstream << a(0) <<"\t" <<
             << a(1) <<"\t" <<
             ...
             << a(n) <<"\n";
```

The return value of `basic_ostream::operator<<` is `basic_ostream &`.

The above could be rewritten as:

```
std::fstream.operator<<( a(0) ).operator<<( "\t" ).operator<<( a(1) )...
```

i.e., a sequence of `std::ostream.operator<<()` calls.

```
std::fstream << a(0);
std::fstream << "\t";
...
std::fstream << a(n);
std::fstream << "\n";
```

This could be rewritten as:

```
std::fstream.operator<<( a(0) );
std::fstream.operator<<( "\t" );
...
```

i.e., a sequence of `std::fstream.operator<<()` calls.

The two ways of writing that output sequence are functionally identical.

The former is less typing, and easier to read IMHO.